# Rules for WHOIS registrant contact details of a .co.nz domain name?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, whois

I understand there are rules on accuracy of contact details for a `.co.nz` domain name, such as requirements on the address being current, the name being of a real person (rather than just "Registrant") etc.

Where can I find these rules? Do they differ by TLD?

Answer (score 2):

These rules actually aren't limited to the domain registrar or the ccTLD regulatory body, but rather imposed globally by ICANN which manages all domains.

https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/contact-verification-2013-05-03-en

So, it is important to update your information if they are no longer current. Penalties include a fine for contact details that aren't updated.

These rules are there to prohibit people from holding a domain indefinitely (or until they expire) without a way to contact them. In fact, you can report a bad whois lookup to the registrar, and they are actually required by ICANN to update this.

Also note that this also prohibits the use of fake information. If they find out that they use fake info, then your domain gets taken away from you.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the `.nz` domain commission website policies page https://www.dnc.org.nz/the-commission/policies, there is no obvious mention of any such rules.

However if you want the definitive answer contact them `info@dnc.org.nz` and ask.

Comment: Thanks... it looks like it's covered in the Principles and Responsibilities document (at your given link) section 9.1.2 for Registrants "Ensure all information given to the Registrar is accurate and complete.". And yes, emailing is a good suggestion too :-)

Comment: @HighlyIrregular I run a web hosting and domain selling business and I have yet to ever hear of someone losing a domain because of incorrect contact details.  In fact with .au there has been an ongoing problem of registrant contact details being lost when I transfer domains from a crappy registrar to a new one.  I was really concerned about it and AUDA told me there wasn't a problem.   Having said all that, obviously email addresses need to be correct for EPP codes and renewal notices.